# Qooxdoo ComboBox Label Function

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I'm using Qooxdoo 2.0 `ComboBox` and `SelectBox` component.
I'm looking for a solution to programmatically define the label of each combo entry.
Something similar to the `labelFunction` or `labelField` properties in the Flex `ComboBox` *(or spark `DropDownList`) componenent.

Thanks 
Davide

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your looking for but the data binding controller might be the stuff you need. Just check out the following demo [1] which shows a select box bound to an array containing strings. The select boxes can be replaced by combo boxes as well.

[1] http://demo.qooxdoo.org/current/demobrowser/#data~SelectBox.html

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to populate the `ComboBox`, or `SelectBox`, with a list ob object with 2 properties, and then set the Combobox to use the first properties as the label and the second one as value.

A the end I used the model property from the the qx.ui.form.ListItem class. to store additional data for each selection.

This is how I populate the ComboBox item.

```
for(var x in data){
    var tempItem = new qx.ui.form.ListItem(data[x]["name"]);
    tempItem.model=data[x];
    combo.add(tempItem);
}
```

And this is How I get the additional values from the selection:

```
combobox.getSelection()[0].model.id
```

Davide